# Ember - dynamically render a different view based on input

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm looking to change a chart being rendered on my page based on the selection a user chooses from a dropdown menu. I'm using the `{{view}}` helper to display the chart, but I think that might be the wrong way to go about.

Right now, I can view the chart by going directly to the URL `#/charts/specificchart` but if I try to transition to that route in my `charts` controller, it doesn't render and the URL doesn't change. `specificchart` is a dynamic segment.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I think I've come up with is to replace the {{view}} with an {{{outlet}}, remove the dynamic segment from the route, and have a separate route for each chart.